# In apache flink with kafka,How to connect to multiple kafka cluster with same group id

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

We are using Apache flink with Kafka. Our flink jobs deployed in 3 datcenter dc1, dc2, dc3. In each data centre, flink job consume messages from their respective data centre kafka cluster.

Now we have changed the design that each flink job cross connects to all 3 data centre of kafka cluster with same group id, but we are receiving duplicates even passing same group id? So how to avoid this duplicates

Wanted to know how to avoid duplicate messages while connecting to multiple clusters of kafka?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear if you're having one Kafka cluster, stretched across 3 data centers, or three Kafka clusters, each running in their own DC.

If you have one Kafka cluster which is stretched across 3 DCs, then you also need to setup one Flink cluster and job which accesses the 3 DCs. If you have three Kafka clusters, then you should also have 3 Flink clusters and jobs.

Comment: Have 3 kafka cluster(kdc1, kdc2, kdc3) and 3 flink cluster(fdc1,fdc2,fdc3). 
A job “Money Debit “ deployed in flink cluster ( fdc1) which cross connects to three kafka clusters. 
The same deployed deployed in another dara centre fdc2 which also connects to all same kafka clusters. Now any message send kafka topic will be consumed by flink job deployed in fdc1, fdc2. But as per the kafka, if we use same consumer group , only one the flink job should consume but here consumed  by  two flink jobs in each flink data centre . So how should avoid consuming same message in different flink clusters

Comment: Flink doesn't use the consumer group mechanism (except for reporting lag), but a more lower level API. It uses its own 2-phase commit protocol for fault tolerance and not the consumer group model. See See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639019/flink-kafka-consumer-groupid-not-working for details.  for a similar question